# Comparing two database which user another database with different name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have total 3 databases for local, pre-release and production. Now the problem in the databases we use on all server have same name. But we are using another database in some of the procedures which has different name on all three servers.

Is there any db compare tool which can help us to find out database differences with above scenario? I dont want procedures that don't have any changes except database name. Or is there any way to solve out this problem?

PS: I am using SQLDBDiff. I can't change other database names on pre-release or production.

Comment: if you're using Visual Studio there's a database compare tool that you can use to compare databases.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Red Gate's SQL Compare, but that's not free.. if you are looking for an open source tool .. i think **Atlantis** can help you.. You can download the SQL Schema Inspector of Atlantis.

http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/